# How to compare class objects containing Optional Instant field using AssertJ taking into account precision difference between Java 8 and Java 11

Tags: java, junit5, assertj

Let's say I have a class such as the following:

```java
class Example {
    Instant normal_Instant;
    Optional<Instant> optional_Instant;
}
```

I want to compare objects of this class for equality using AssertJ 3.12.2. One problem is that Java 11 increased the precision of the Instant type so I added a custom `Comparator` to handle that using AssertJ's `withComparatorForType` method. But this does not work for `Instant` fields that are wrapped in `Optional`.

How can I handle such a scenario?

The following is the code I wrote to deal with this scenario but it feels clunky:

```java
public static <T> void assertObjectsWithInstantComparator(T obj1, T obj2) {
        Comparator<Instant> instantComparator = Comparator.comparing(i -> i.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS));

        Assertions.assertThat(obj1)
                .usingRecursiveComparison()
                .withComparatorForType(instantComparator, Instant.class)
                .withComparatorForType(TestUtil::compareOptionalInstants, Optional.class)
                .isEqualTo(obj2);
    }

    private static int compareOptionalInstants(Optional<Instant> opt1, Optional<Instant> opt2) {
        if (opt1.isPresent() && opt2.isPresent()) {
            Object value1 = opt1.get();
            Object value2 = opt2.get();

            if (value1 instanceof Instant && value2 instanceof Instant) {
                return compareInstants((Instant) value1, (Instant) value2);
            } else {
                return value1.equals(value2) ? 0 : -1;
            }
        } else if (opt1.isPresent()) {
            return 1; // opt1 is present, but opt2 is not
        } else if (opt2.isPresent()) {
            return -1; // opt2 is present, but opt1 is not
        } else {
            return 0; // both optionals are empty
        }
    }

    private static int compareInstants(Instant i1, Instant i2) {
        return i1.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS).compareTo(i2.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS));
    }
```

Is there maybe a way to register a second `Comparator` for `Optional` instances containing `Instant` values?

I am also open to solutions using some other library or tool such as Hamcrest. Or, does Junit 5 have an in-built way of achieving this?

Following is a minimal, reproducible example to demonstrate that the test will fail for the `Optional<Instant>` field:

```java
@Test
public void AssertJ_Test() {
// The Instant values generated for testing using Instant.now() will have nanosecond precision in Java 11
Instant normal_instant_test = Instant.parse("2023-06-20T23:45:54.028812Z");
Optional<Instant> opt_instant_test = Optional.of(Instant.parse("2023-06-20T23:45:54.028812Z"));

// The Instant values retrieved from Cassandra will have millisecond precision
Instant normal_instant_DB = Instant.parse("2023-06-20T23:45:54.028Z");
Optional<Instant> opt_instant_DB = Optional.of(Instant.parse("2023-06-20T23:45:54.028Z"));

Example test_obj = Example
                        .builder()
                        .normal_Instant(normal_instant_test)
                        .optional_Instant(opt_instant_test)
                        .build();

Example db_obj = Example
        .builder()
        .normal_Instant(normal_instant_DB)
        .optional_Instant(opt_instant_DB)
        .build();

Comparator<Instant> instantComparator = Comparator.comparing(i -> i.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS));

org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat(db_obj)
        .usingRecursiveComparison()
        .withStrictTypeChecking()
        .withComparatorForType(instantComparator, Instant.class)
        .isEqualTo(test_obj);
}

class Example {
    Instant normal_Instant;
    Optional<Instant> optional_Instant;
}
```

Comment: The first comparator should be enough. What makes you think it needs to be customized for Optional?

Comment: @shmosel my tests fail when I remove the compareOptionalInstants, apparently AssertJ does not apply my instantComparator for Instant fields wrapped in Optional, I guess due to type erasure at runtime, so then it just compares the Optional<Instant> fields normally which runs into the Java 11 precision problem that I mentioned. I get error message like `field/property 'optional_Instant' differ:
- actual value   : Optional[2023-06-20T23:45:54.028Z]
- expected value : Optional[2023-06-20T23:45:54.028812Z]`

Comment: It works for me. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the problem either, see https://github.com/assertj/assertj/commit/0fad4c0c1e72ac0dae9e4939e879be74264da259. What AssertJ version are you using?

Comment: Hi @StefanoCordio, I have added a MRE to my original post that demonstrates how the Instant comparator fails for Optional Instants, please have a look. Also I am using AssertJ version 3.12.2

Comment: Hi @Ghos3t, you are on quite an old version. Is there any chance you can upgrade to 3.24.2?

Comment: @StefanoCordio I realized that from your last message and so I upgraded to 3.24.2 and that solved my problem, I also added this as the solution at the top of my post. If you want you can even mention this as a answer to this question and I will mark it as the solution, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AssertJ 3.12 had the very first implementation of the recursive comparison, which did not compare `Optional` values recursively. However, this has been improved in [3.13.0](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-3.13.0-optional-support-in-recursive-comparison):

> The recursive comparison added in 3.12.0 now compares `Optional` values recursively instead of comparing `Optional` with equals.

Upgrading to 3.13.0 or [later](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core/) should fix the issue.